# Is there a way to define a type constructor that includes a bunch of type constraints?

Tags: haskell

I have a big bunch of data types and functions on two type variables that require that the types are `Eq`, `Ord`, and `Show`. I found myself writing

```
type Foo n t = (Eq n, Eq t, Ord n, Ord t, Show n, Show t) => Bar n t -- and
data Baz n t where
  Baz :: (Eq n, Eq t, Ord n, Ord t, Show n, Show t) => {
    f1 :: !n,
    f2 :: !t
  } -> Baz n t
```

all over the place.

Is there a way to write something like

```
type EqOrdShow d n t = (Eq n, Eq t, Ord n, Ord t, Show n, Show t) => d n t
```

such that I could write

```
type Foo n t = EqOrdShow Foo n t -- and
data Baz n t where
  Baz :: {f1 :: !n, f2 :: !t} -> EqOrdShow Baz n t
```

or some other way of giving a name to the list of constraints to avoid repeating it?

Comment: Note that `(Eq n, Ord n)` is redundant to begin with, since `Ord`  is a subclass of `Eq`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define an alias for the constraint:

```
type EqOrdShow n t = (Eq n, Eq t, Ord n, Ord t, Show n, Show t)

data Baz n t where
  Baz :: EqOrdShow n t => {f1 :: !n, f2 :: !t} -> Baz n t
```

I don't think you can avoid having to write `-> Baz something something` explicitly at the end of the type of each constructor.

---

Also keep in mind that the record fields are not so useful here. For instance, the following won't work

```
foo :: Baz n t -> String
foo x = show (f1 x)
-- No instance for (Show n) arising from a use of `show'
```

since only pattern matching can bring the `Show n` constraint in scope. You'll need to use something like

```
foo2 :: Baz n t -> String
foo2 Baz{f1=y} = show y
```

Comment: Ah, so the secret is to _not_ try to get the `=>` in the definition. Thank you very much!

Comment: Should I expect to have to add `ConstraintKinds` and `ImpredicativeTypes`?

Comment: @ToddO'Bryan I tried GHC 9.2.2 and that did not require anything for the simple test above. Perhaps `ConstraintKinds` and/or `GADTs` is required for other uses (?). I can't see why `ImpredicativeTypes` would be required.

Comment: @ToddO'Bryan `ConstraintKinds` is harmless and useful. If the compiler ever tells you you need it you should probably just turn it on (I would have no hesitation in enabling it by default without thinking about it much). `ImpredicativeTypes` is a red flag, to me. Until relatively recently it was "supported" by GHC, but very broken. I think it actually works these days, but if the compiler tells me my code requires `ImpredicativeTypes` it's still more likely that I've made a mistake than that I actually should be using it. I would only turn it on very deliberately.

Comment: @chi `ConstraintKinds` is part of `GHC2021`; could that be why you didn't have to turn it on explicitly?